# Python вывод информации с лог файла в консоль и очистка консоли с последующим выводом

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код:

```
flog2 = open('log_2.txt', 'w')
for word in currentDict.keys():
    flog2.write("%s %d\n" % (word, currentDict[word]))

    print("%s %d" % (word, currentDict[word]))
```

Выводит информацию с лог файла о данных:

> Лог файл:
>
> слово1 - 1
>
> слово2 - 1
>
> слово№ - N

Проблема в том, что в консоли получается после вывода информации, следующая идет следом и тяжело найти откуда новая поступила(началась).
Необходимо очистить(?) консоль и вывести по новой данные
Т.е. сейчас:

> Слово1 - 1

Затем появилось Слово2
и получается

> Слово1 - 1
>
> Слово1 - 1
>
> Слово2 - 1

В след раз

> Слово1 - 1
>
> Слово1 - 1
>
> Слово2 - 1
>
> Слово1 - 2
>
> Слово2 - 1,...

А хотелось бы увидеть после изменения информации в файле только такое в консоле:

> Слово1 - 2
>
> Слово2 - 1,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поиграться с символов `\r` – перевод каретки, пример:

```
for i in range(5):
    print('Word {}'.format(i))


print()
for i in range(5):
    print('Word {}'.format(i), end='\r')

print()
```

Консоль:

```
Word 0
Word 1
Word 2
Word 3
Word 4

Word 4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Да, как вариант, можно и так...

Comment: Так-то доступ к консоли из программы получить сложно, если бы была такая нужда, я бы сделал с гуи (Qt) и через виджет выводил логи и чистил, когда хотел )